# Blocking function in node.js application

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading, asynchronous

I am creating a node.js application. One of its functions is to upload an excel file, then read it and save its contents in the database. The problem's that I am new to node.js and I don't understand the concept of non-blocking code so it seems this function blocks the main thread, so I need some help to solve this issue.

```
app.post('/admin/upload_file', function(req, res) {
    var sampleFile;
    if (!req.files) {
        res.send('No files were uploaded.');
        console.log('No files were uploaded.');
        return;
    }
    sampleFile = req.files.sampleFile;
    var fileArray = sampleFile.name.split('.');
    var extension = fileArray[fileArray.length - 1];
    if (extension == "xlsx") {
        sampleFile.mv('./public/uploads/sample_file.xlsx', function(err) {
            if (err) {
                res.status(500).send(err);
            } else {
                var entries = parsing_file(req, res);
                if (entries.length > 0) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
                        // this loop on database queries block the main thread
                        model.insert_in_db(entries[0], function(rows) {});
                    }
                }
                res.redirect('/admin');
            }
        });
    } else {
        res.redirect('/admin');
  }
});
```

The `parsing_file` function parses the file and stores the values as objects into an array, the problem starts when the loop on the database query (which is responsible for inserting the values in the db) starts as the main thread of node.js becomes blocked until the loop has completed its work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use fs.readFile to read data from your file it is async operation and use  async.eachLimit instead of for loop it is non blocking async operation while for loop if sync operation

```
 fs.readFile('./public/uploads/sample_file.xlsx', function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            res.status(500).send(err);
        } else {
            var entries = parsing_file(req, res);                
            if (entries.length > 0) {
                async.eachLimit(entries, 10, function(entrie, callback){                      
                    model.insert_in_db(entrie, function(rows) {callback()});
                },function(err){
                      if( err ) {
                         // One of the iterations produced an error.
                         // All processing will now stop.
                         console.log('A file failed to process');
                      } else {
                          console.log('All files have been processed 
                          successfully');
                          return res.redirect('/admin');
                      }
               })                
        }           
  });
```

read https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#eachLimit async documentation for more details.

Comment: That 's exactly what I am looking for especially regarding the part of `async.eachLimit` but do you know, what is the best practices to set the limitation number? or it depends on the time that the query take to be done?

Comment: async.leachLimit is used to set maximum number of async operations at a time. as eachlimit runs in parallel so if there are thousands of records to save of to loop then nodes callstack will be full and throws an error Call stack limit reached. so to avoid this we use limit to run limited records in parallel and after there execution loop next records in parallel. limitation number depends on you logic inside eachLimit function  that what are you doing there.

Answer (score -2):

**TL;DR**
I do not know what is the actual implementation of the `insert_in_db` method, but it seems to be a synchronous method. Of this is the case, your code is actually blocked by that method.

However In my opinion it's not a great idea having async code writing in a db, in order to avoid problems related to accessing the same record at the same time.

In short, if that method is blocking there must be a reason for that.